# Virtualenv - new environment has a lot of default dependencies

Tags: django, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper, django-1.8

I have `Virtualenv` installed on my Macbook. I want to create a new environment, where I can develop a nice app.

I was expecting an empty virtual environment, to make it easy to deploy and keep dependencies down.

However, after I `virtualenv MyAppName`, it generates a new virtual environment with the `bin`, `include` and `lib` folders.

When I `pip freeze < requirements.txt` , I get this long list:

```
altgraph==0.10.2
bdist-mpkg==0.5.0
beautifulsoup4==4.3.2
bonjour-py==0.3
Django==1.8.1
macholib==1.5.1
matplotlib==1.3.1
modulegraph==0.10.4
numpy==1.8.0rc1
pbr==0.11.0
py2app==0.7.3
pyobjc-core==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-Accounts==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-AddressBook==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-AppleScriptKit==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-AppleScriptObjC==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-Automator==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-CFNetwork==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-Cocoa==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-Collaboration==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-CoreData==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-CoreLocation==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-CoreText==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-DictionaryServices==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-EventKit==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-ExceptionHandling==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-FSEvents==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-InputMethodKit==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-InstallerPlugins==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-InstantMessage==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-LatentSemanticMapping==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-LaunchServices==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-Message==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-OpenDirectory==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-PreferencePanes==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-PubSub==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-QTKit==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-Quartz==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-ScreenSaver==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-ScriptingBridge==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-SearchKit==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-ServiceManagement==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-Social==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-SyncServices==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-SystemConfiguration==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-WebKit==2.5.1
pyOpenSSL==0.13.1
pyparsing==2.0.1
python-dateutil==1.5
python-memcached==1.54
pytz==2013.7
requests==2.7.0
scipy==0.13.0b1
six==1.9.0
stevedore==1.4.0
Twisted==13.2.0
virtualenv==12.1.1
virtualenv-clone==0.2.5
virtualenvwrapper==4.5.1
xattr==0.6.4
zope.interface==4.1.1
```

I would expect no dependencies. What am I doing wrong here?

***Disclaimer***: Newbie to virtualenv who only read the documentation and saw multiple Youtube videos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Understand this process,
Create virtual environment

```
~$ virtualenv MyAppName
```

Then you should do

This is command for activating virtual environment

```
~$ source MyAppName/bin/activate
```

Then your pip freeze comes.

```
~$ pip freeze > requirements.txt
```